# How to disable HTML validation tooltips for input elements without a <form>

Tags: html, angularjs, validation

I know that, if I have an `input` within a `<form>` element, I can simply add the `novalidate` attribute to the form to disable the HTML validation tooltips. However, my input is not in a form element (I am using AngularJS and I use the `ng-form` directive).

I can listen to the [invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/invalid) event and prevent submit validation, but I cannot prevent validation tooltips.

Here is a simple [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arashsoft/ab3sb5fs/2/) to show the issue.

Comment: Why do you have the `required` attribute if you don't really care about the field validating?

Comment: @ScottMarcus, I handle it with angular validation with my customized tooltips.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In HTML you have two options for input elements:

1. Put them inside a `<form>` container.
2. Add the `form` attribute to the input, the value should be the `id` of the form that the input is related to.

Using option #2 you can just add an empty form with the `novalidate` somewhere in your DOM and attach the input to that form:

```html
<form novalidate>
  <p>Input in form with novalidate. This one is fine.</p>
  <input type="email" required>
</form>

<p>Input without form. How to disable validation tooltips? (hover over input to see validation tooltip)</p>
<input type="email" required form="novalidatedform">

<form id="novalidatedform" novalidate />
```

More information regarding the `input` element in [MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input).

Comment: Surprisingly adding `form` attribute in input elements worked perfectly in angularJS framework. As I mentioned in the question, I am using `ng-form` directive to handle validation in angular way. Adding form attribute to inputs did not break angular validation while it prevents HTML5 validation. Tested in Chrome, Firefox, IE 10+. Thanks a lot.

Comment: the "angular way" is to use ```<form name="myform">``` and the inputs inside there, then you will have access to the formController from ```$scope.myform``` ej. ```$scope.$myform.$valid```

Answer (score 14):

Although [Dekel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45620802/how-to-disable-html-validation-tooltips-for-input-elements-without-a-form/45621035#45621035) does the job, another way how this could be done is by simply adding a 'title' attribute to the input element, and the validation message will be overwritten with the content in title attribute.

You can add some meaningful text in the title attribute,

```
<input type="email" title="Your Email">
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use this script

```
<script>
    document.getElementById( "inputId" ).addEventListener( "invalid",
        function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
</script>
```